# How do I increase the token amount? (BEP20)

Tags: solidity, remix, bep20

I created BEP20 token via remix, now I want to increase this token amount. How can I make 100 thousand tokens 200 thousand?

Answer (score 0):

you need add a mint function, like this blow

```
function issue(uint amount) public onlyOwner {
    require(_totalSupply + amount > _totalSupply);
    require(balances[owner] + amount > balances[owner]);

    balances[owner] += amount;
    _totalSupply += amount;
    Issue(amount);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add this to the constructor funtion? I copied codes here : https://github.com/bnb-chain/bsc-genesis-contract/blob/master/contracts/bep20_template/BEP20Token.template

Comment: The function `function mint(uint256 amount) public onlyOwner returns (bool)` will help you increasing token more from link.

Comment: thank you so bro, can you send me example link? i'm not understand sikik :S